# Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created an interface of User to put in some value from ngModel. Take a look at this.

user.ts

```
export class User{
    _id: String;
    username: String;
    password: String;
    firstname: String;
    lastname: String;
    gender: String;
    address: String;
    contact: Number;
    email?: String;
}
```

Example of ngModel binding

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.username" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter your Username" formControlName="username"/>
```

Output from the console log

[image]

I want to make the result to a json. I use JSON.parse but the error on the title pops up. How can I convert it to a json object? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JSON.parse` is meant for creating a javascript object from a string (that is already formatted for JSON). What you're looking for is `JSON.stringify` instead to convert your javascript object into JSON text.

Comment: i think this is a dumb question but do you consider the User to be a JSON object?

Comment: @MixAustria there's no such thing as a "JSON object" in JavaScript. Your user type is simply an object, and any JavaScript object can be turned into a JSON string.

Comment: `User` is a javascript object in this case. JSON is "Javascript Object Notation", which is a text-based format to represent objects in javascript (many great definitions out there to learn more about the difference)

Comment: JSON text would be a string in Javascript that represents the User object, such as "{ _id:'1', username:'abc' /**... and so on ...**/ }"

Comment: now I pass this object to an express server and here is what I got on the request body. kindly see this please http://prntscr.com/dkfgwy There are \n on the object and I cannot access it for example req.body.username etc. can you tell my why?

Comment: Not sure how your newlines are getting injected (maybe from a copy/paste). I suppose you either do a string replace or write a quick replacer function to pass into your `stringify` (see http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/filter.php) to string out newlines.